# How do I take the scrollbar into account with viewport width units?

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to develop a carousel similar to Netflix, but I cannot make it responsive. I have been using a codepen example:

[Link to example](http://codepen.io/joshhunt/pen/LVQZRa)

In this example, it has a hardcoded width and height. I would like to make it use a responsive measure (percentages). I wanted to use the `vw` viewport width units, but this doesn't work for me because it does not exclude the scrollbar. So, when I want every carousel item to have a width of 20vw (so that each one is 20% of the viewport size), they are always wider than I want because the viewport does not exclude the scrollbar.

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: That link does not work. Responsive slideshow and caroussels are not hard to make, but we will need to see the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to better reflect what it is you're trying to get help with. I also improved the grammar of your question, and fixed the url to your codepen example. (It's very important to make sure that links to supporting resources are correct, or people may not take the time to answer your question!) I also removed the netflix tag, because this question does not itself involve Netflix. Good luck with finding an answer!

Comment: The link is http://codepen.io/joshhunt/pen/LVQZRa I know that is not difficult. The complex is how Netflix do it. Because when you do hover on ítem the width is increased

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example: [Link](http://codepen.io/nitsuga/pen/LGzMrx)

In this example, I want to show five items and showing an arrow on the right. The 6th item should be hidden behind the arrow, but the arrow width is not correct.

The width of every item is 18.4vw ( (100-8)/5=18.4). As you can see, I have put a padding on left and right with 4vw(so, I am subtracting 8 for total width), so, I have made the arrow layer with:

```
position:absolute;
right:0;
width:4vw;
```

In this manner, the arrow always is fixed to right.

The problem is that 18.4vw is the measure respect the viewport, and as there is a scrollbar, the width is not correct, because the scrollbar width is breaking the correct measure.

I dont know if you understand what I want to make.

BR.